# Laravel 5 route prefix

Tags: php, laravel-5

I would like to have a route prefixed by a country. Like this:

```
/us/shop
/ca/shop
/fr/shop
```

My idea was to do so:

```php
<?php

Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{country}'
], function() {
    Route::get('shop', 'ShopController@Index');
    // ...
});
```

This works. My problem is that I'd like to autoload the `Country` for each sub route and be able to use it from the controller as well as the view.

Any hints?

Comment: Aren't those countries going to have different languages as well?

Comment: @dan-klasson it's more of a generic question, but we can assume thatthey will.

Comment: Why not just use Laravel Localization then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution, I've came up with relies on a specific middleware.

```php
<?php

Route::get('', function() {
    return redirect()->route('index', ['language' => App::getLocale()]);
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => '{lang}',
    'where' => ['lang' => '(fr|de|en)'],
    'middleware' => 'locale'
], function() {

    Route::get('', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex']);

    // ...

}
```

and the middleware.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App;
use Closure;
use View;

class Localization {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $language = $request->route()->parameter('lang');

        App::setLocale($language);

        // Not super necessary unless you really want to use
        // number_format or even money_format.
        if ($language == "en") {
            setLocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
        } else {
            setLocale(LC_ALL, $language."_CH.UTF-8");
        }

        View::share('lang', $language);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

As you can guess, this code was meant for a swiss application, hence the `_CH` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is using the [segment](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_segment) function of the `Request` facade:

```
$country = Request::segment(1);
```