# Laravel prefix and AJAX

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, prefix

**PROBLEM: AJAX request not working with prefix**

Website works great without language prefix. But I need it.. So before (no middleware) and ajax post to domain.com/*entitlement* worked great.

However, when posting with prefix (domain.com/**en**/*entitlement*) and having the  pre-fix middleware on throws an error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:`

The stackoverflow posts I have seen on prefix routing are focusing on GET related issues. Like [Laravel 5 route prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593582/laravel-5-route-prefix). I have a POST issue (the GET works fine)

Any ideas?

**ROUTES**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
       'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ]
    ],
    function()
    {

        Route::get('/', array(
            'as' => 'home',
            'uses' => 'HomeController@getHome'
        ));

        Route::post('/entitlement', array(
            'as' => 'entitlement-post',
            'uses' => 'HomeController@postEntlitment'
        ));
    }
}
```

**AJAX REQUEST**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/entitlement', --> Becomes domain.com/en/entitlement
    data: data,
    dataType:'json',
    beforeSend: function() { 
    },
...
```

**LocalizationSessionRedirect**

```
<?php namespace Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Closure;

class LocaleSessionRedirect {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle( $request, Closure $next )
    {
        $params = explode('/', $request->path());
        $locale = session('locale', false);

        if ( count($params) > 0 && $locale = app('laravellocalization')->checkLocaleInSupportedLocales($params[ 0 ]) )
        {
            session([ 'locale' => $params[ 0 ] ]);

            return $next($request);
        }

        if ( $locale && app('laravellocalization')->checkLocaleInSupportedLocales($locale) && !( app('laravellocalization')->getDefaultLocale() === $locale && app('laravellocalization')->hideDefaultLocaleInURL() ) )
        {
            app('session')->reflash();
            $redirection = app('laravellocalization')->getLocalizedURL($locale);

            return new RedirectResponse($redirection, 302, [ 'Vary' => 'Accept-Language' ]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the URL in the Ajax request still need the language prefix or is that what `localizationRedirect` is supposed to do? Maybe you can show us that if that's the case?

Comment: @tptcat Thanks for quick response. The AJAX is built dynamically so the failed POST is domain.com/en/entitlement. Updated the question with the localizationSessionRedirect from Mcamara library

Comment: Look here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/mcamaralaravel-localization-usage-and-understanding-need-help?page=1

Comment: Thanks @tptcat! Solved the issue!

Comment: Was it removing the `localizationRedirect` Middleware?

Comment: @tptcat yes. In essence routes still work with domain.com/LANG/route but it does not add the /LANG/ part automatically. Added your answer below. But if you want some points feel free to add your answer and I'll accept it :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to tptcat the answer is to take out middleware of Mcmara's redirect.

**UPDATED ROUTE**

```
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
//       'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect' ] --> Not included
    ],
    function()
    {
```